# Как создать список объектов с определённым именем?

Tags: python

Мне надо создать n объектов класса Units(). Имена их должны буть разными и взяты из списка units_names. Ели вы бредоставите решение ПОЖАЛУЙСТА напишите что мне надо изучить, чтобы понять это всё(можете просто написть, что мне надо изучить)!

```
class Units():
    #Описание класса

units_names=[]
for i in range(1,n):
    units_names += str("unit_" + i)

units=[]    
for k in range(1,n):
    units.append(Units(units_names[n])) #Пытаюсь что-то сделать
```

Comment: Что Вы понимаете под именами?

Comment: a = 3. a - имя, 3 - значение.

Comment: Вы хотите, чтобы объекты были записаны в переменные с разным названием?

Comment: в этих случаях обычно используют словарь. В качестве ключей словаря будут выступать имена...

Comment: @hedgehogues, именно так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать для этого функцию `exec`.
Эта функция исполняет переданную ей строку как код на Python.

Предупреждаю, что использовать её рекомендуется, только если Вы точно уверены в правильности и безопасности передаваемых ей строк.

***Пример:***

```py
class Unit:
    pass

units_names = ['unit_' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]

for name in units_names:
    cmd = '%s = Unit()' % name
    exec(cmd)

print(unit_1)
```

*stdout:*

```py
<__main__.Unit object at 0x0340CC50>  # Экземпляр класса Unit
```

В переменной `cmd` формируются команды вида: `unit_n = Unit()`.
Они передаются на исполнение и по окончании цикла мы будем иметь 5 переменных.

---

***P. S.:***
1) Желательно называть классы в ед. ч.
2) `['unit_' + str(i) for i in range(1, 6)]` - это генератор списка. Эквивалент Вашему коду, но более быстрый и компактный.

Comment: А можно сделать так, чтобы было например <__main__.Unit object at (выбранное мной место)> ?

Comment: @ВладимирПолихатко Я плохо Вас понимаю. `0x0340CC50` в примере - это место в памяти. Каждый запуск программы оно будет разное. Что система выделит, то мы и получим. Я привёл `stdout` только чтобы показать, что созданные переменные действительно экземпляры класса `Unit`.

Comment: @ nomnoms12 дело в том, что мне надо создать 12(объектов) шашек с разными именами, т.е. при 1-ом проходе цикла создаётся объект unit_1, при 2-ом проходе unit_2 и так далее... Можете посоветовать каким образом мне действовать, и стоит ли мне вообще использовать выбранный мной метод решения?

Comment: @ВладимирПолихатко Мой код делает то, что Вы сказали. В цикле создаются переменные `unit_1`, `unit_2` и т. д. Они ссылаются на уникальные экземпляры класса `Unit`. Как раз то, что Вам нужно. Вариант не лучший, но советовать не берусь.